# What is the PKG_PATH for NetBSD 6.0.1 Binary Installs?

Tags: software-installation, bsd, netbsd

What is the value or URL for `PKG_PATH` used to inform NetBSD 6.0.1 where to download binary packages from? There seems to be a change in both servers as well as the path or directory layout for the packages directory. I have tried and failed to figure it out. I am using NetBSD on an `i386` architecture.

Comment: This should be answered autoritatively at http://netbsd.org. What makes you think we here know better?

Comment: @vonbrand - the netbsd.org documentation is out of date and it rambles on without providing answer simple questions like above.

Answer (score 5):

```
http://ftp.NetBSD.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/$(uname -s)/$(uname -m)/$(uname -r|cut -f '1 2' -d.)/All
```

The above code should work for every version of NetBSD you have.

Source: [The PKGSRC WEBPAGE](http://www.pkgsrc.org/)

Comment: The next question is, where do we add it so its exported for whatever shell is default.

Comment: It really depends on the shell in question. The `export` command (specified in the quickstart section of the website) should work for sh and related shells (I.E, Bash), for csh and tcsh use `setenv` . I haven't used netbsd in ages, but since pkgsrc is their default package manager that should work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

The PKG_PATH is `ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/i386/6.0/All/`

(stackexchange won't let me enter a short answer, so here goes)